# I need to update the existing user roles through REST service in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

How can I add/remove an existing user role through the REST service in Marklogic? if possible can you share the sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST endpoint [PUT /manage/v2/users/{id|name}/properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/users/%5Bid-or-name%5D/properties).

For example, if you wanted to update the user **test** and assign them the *admin* role (and update the user description):

```
curl -X PUT -i --digest -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @payload.json http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/users/test/properties
```

with the following JSON in a file called payload.json:

```
{
  "description": "updated roles example",
  "roles": [{"role": "admin" }]
}
```